# How to have items inline with a <td> tag

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have the follow Td tag:

```
 <td>
              <span>
                {{ device.id }}<CopyComponent
                  :copy-content="device.id"
                  color="white"
                />
              </span>
            </td>
```

and this is the contents of the component:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="copyContent!==undefined">
    <button
      :id="copyContent"
      @click="doCopy"
    >
      <font-awesome-icon
        :icon="myIcon"
        style="color:white;"
      />
    </button>
    <b-tooltip
      ref="idToolTip"
      :show.sync="show"
      :target="copyContentString"
      title="Click to copy"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Just a button really, however for some reason when the table is being displayed the button appears under the id instead of the the right of it. I've done the hacky approach of placing `style="display: inline;"` in almost everywhere but it still displays underneath :( what am i missing from styling or alignment to fix this?

Comment: Make sure your table cell is wide enough to accommodate both the text and the button. Or mark it as `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: this done the fix